# Inconsistent View Hierarchy

Tags: cocoa, xib, nsview

I try to add a .xib based custom view into another .xib based custom view. 
The result is looking like this:

```
for sub in v.subviews {
      Swift.print(v.subviews) // returns array [sub]
      Swift.print(sub) // returns sub
      Swift.print(sub.superview) // return nil!
}
```

How can a view be in superview's subviews, but the superview property not correctly set? Can this happen during de/coding? What do I need to set in order for this to be correct?

The next question would be, why `sub` is shown correctly in "View Debugging" but not in when I need it during run time.

**EDIT:** (thanks Matt for looking into this)
My Code looks like this:

```
import AppKit
func showXIBDefinedInPanel(name: String, title: String ) {
    if let w = loadXIBDefined(name: name) {
        let c = NSViewController()
        c.view = w
        let window = NSPanel(contentViewController: c)
        window.isMovable = true
        window.collectionBehavior = .canJoinAllSpaces
        window.tabbingMode = .disallowed
        window.title = title
        window.styleMask = [ .titled,  .utilityWindow, .closable]
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(w)
    }
}

func loadXIBDefined(name: String) -> XIBDefined? {
    var topLevelObjects : NSArray?
    var result : XIBDefined? = nil
    if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: name), owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
        result = topLevelObjects!.first(where: { $0 is XIBDefined }) as? XIBDefined
    }
    return result
}

///used to embed a XIBDefined into another XIB
@IBDesignable class XIBEmbedder : NSView {

    // Our custom view from the XIB file
    var view: NSView!
    var xibName: String!

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        view = loadXIBDefined(name: xibName)
        addSubview(view)
        self.frame = view.frame
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        view = loadXIBDefined(name: xibName)
        addSubview(view)
        self.frame = view.frame
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.xibName = name
        super.init(frame: NSZeroRect)
        view = loadXIBDefined(name: xibName)
        addSubview(view)
        self.frame = view.frame
    }
}

///used as class for XIB based Custom Views
@IBDesignable class XIBDefined: NSView {

    ///I had an issue with an oddly moved frame, so I hard coded a fix
    override func setFrameOrigin(_ newOrigin: NSPoint) {
        super.setFrameOrigin(NSZeroPoint)
        needsDisplay = true
    }
}


@IBDesignable class WelcomeCMapView : XIBEmbedder {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Welcome Concept Maps")
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(name: "Welcome Concept Maps")
    }
}
```

Key are the two classes `XIBDefined` and `XIBEmbedder`. Former one can be loaded from a XIB, the latter can be used in an XIB. Therefore the later embedded XIB uses `XIBDefined` as the custom class, the embedding XIB has a `WelcomeCMapView` as custom class.

The problem-showing code on top is part of the post-processing, which is executed within `viewDidLoad()` from the `NSViewController` loading the embedding XIB.

Comment: "Can this happen during de/coding" That's the question, all right. Nib-loading is fairly involved, and things take a while to get hooked up. A lot depends on _when_ you are saying this. Can you pan the camera backwards and show more of the surrounding context?

Comment: Also how can you not know what the superview is supposed to be when in fact you just said it was `v`? Evidently the code here is not your real code. Please show your real code, in context. Help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is `window` released at the end of `showXIBDefinedInPanel`? How can `xibName` be not `nil` in `XIBEmbedder.init?(coder:)`? Does the XIB have one top level object? `WelcomeCMapView.init?(coder:)` calls `super.init(name:)` instead of `super.init?(coder:)` and doesn't read properties (superview, frame, …) from the XIB.

Comment: xibName was @IBInspectable in previous version, but I use the derived class right now. And yes, there is only one XIB top level object. However, the whole stuff becomes really mystical (for me) when in Xcode View Debugging all subviews of XIBEmbedder are correctly shown, but not in the window. It doesn't seem to be an issue of AlphaValue or isHidden.